# eclipse indigo autocomplete does not work for a maven svn project

Tags: eclipse, svn, maven, autocomplete

I hate ta ask the same question that seems to hav been asked so many times but I get this error when I attempt autocomplete with eclipse indigo on a maven svn project; None of the answers given seem to work
'this compilation unit is not on the build path of a java project'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just posting the answer in case somene is lost same way I was
I just added the bold sections below in my .project file

this still left me with imports that cant be resolved so autocomplete does not work all the way - to solve this I had to add specific jars from the maven repository in the build path - seems eclipse will just not add these automatically even if I have the maven repository
 variable in the build path

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <projectDescription>
        <name>MYPROJECT</name>
        <comment></comment>
        <projects>
        </projects>
        <buildSpec>
               <!--Added this buildcommand section  -->
            <buildCommand>
                <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
                <arguments>
                </arguments>
            </buildCommand>
            <buildCommand>
                <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
                <arguments>
                </arguments>
            </buildCommand>
        </buildSpec>
        <natures>
            <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
               <!--Added this nature section  -->
            <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>        
        </natures>
    </projectDescription>
```

Comment: Unless you are using a very old m2e plugin, I believe all these should be handled by m2e already, if you are importing the maven project correctly, and has performed "Update project configuration" in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you did not add your project metadata in SVN. It's files like .project, .classpath and the .settings folder in project root. If you still have access to the project in the original workspace, you can find those files and add them to SVN. Otherwise, you will need to recreate a Java project and import your source code.

Comment: its a 3rd party repository, I dont have core developer access to the repository - my solution above only works partially - now its showing errors such as The declared package "org.." does not match the expected 
 package "web.src.main.java.org...."   and imports cannot be resolved so my methods cannot autocomplete

Comment: You have to go to Project Properties -> Java Build Path and configure source root, which appears to be /web/src folder in your project. You will likely need to do quite a bit of work on Java Build Path page to create a valid configuration for this project.